# What's the most efficient way to handle objects which may or may not have nested objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, error-handling

Say I receive the following Object:

```
Response: Shipment {
             Package: {
                  Activity: {}
                  PackageWeight: {}
             }
}
```

That would be the base format, however depending on the request, There could be multiple `Packages` or multiple `Shipments`, etc.

So currently I have unwieldly `if` statements setup where I essentially have:

`if (pyLd.TrackResponse.Shipment.Package.length > 1 )`
and
`if (pyLd.TrackResponse.Shipment.Package[0].Activity.length > 1)`
`else if (pyLd.TrackResponse.Shipment.Package.Activity.length > 1)`

etc. etc.

Is there a better way to do this? I've thought to have [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (example below) but even that is getting unwieldy.

```js
 // check if more than one shipment
  let multiShip = () => {
     if ( pyLd.TrackResponse?.Shipment[1] !== undefined ) {
         // single shipment
         return 'single'
     }

     else {
         return 'multi'
     }
  }

  let multiPackage = () => {
      // check if multi shipment
      if (multiShip.match(/single/gi)){
          // single shipment, how many packages?
          if (pyLd.TrackResponse.Shipment?.Package[1] !== undefined){
              //single shipment, single package
              return {
                  shipments: 1,
                  packages: 1
              }
          }

          else {
              // single shipment, multi package
              return {
                  shipments: 1,
                  packages: 2
              }
          }
      }

      else {
          //multi shipment
          if (pyLd.TrackResponse.Shipment[0].Package[1] !== undefined){
              //multi shipment, single package
              return {
                  shipments: 2,
                  packages: 1
              }
          }

          else {
              // multi shipment, multi package
              return {
                  shipments: 2,
                  packages: 2
              }

          }

      }
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So sometimes `Response.Shipment` is an array of objects, sometimes it’s a single object? Same for `Package`? (That’s bad API design…) Try something like `return { shipments: Response.Shipment.length ?? 1, packages: Response.Shipment[0]?.Package?.length ?? Response.Shipment.Package.length ?? 1 }`. What if `Response.Shipment[0]` and `Response.Shipment[1]` have a different number of Packages?

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks for the comment. `Response.Shipment[0]` and `Response.Shipment[1]` invariably will have different # of packages. There could be deeper nested objects that have the same structure. This is the UPS API via their `https://onlinetools.ups.com/json/Track` endpoint which I fetch through my NodeJS server and return the JSON via a POST request. Anyway, I was thinking that I'd need to do some pre-processing in my server on the JSON response by coupling `Object.keys()` and  `Array.prototype.forEach()` but I'm concerned about the CPU usage on every request made...